# Lost root password on a ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, troubleshooting, installation, passwords

I lost the password for root on a ubuntu virtual machine. Is there any way to restore it or I need to install a new virtual machine with ubuntu again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your root password by running `sudo passwd root`

Comment: ohhh great!!! I was desperated for an hour :-s thanks bro!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't have a password for the root account, unless you explicitly enable it after installing. Sudo will ask for your current account's password, by default.